# To update primefaces datatable cell edited value to database.

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am trying to update datatable cell edited value to database on calling ajax onCellEdit event method.In this method i am using the header name of cell edited column and new value got in update query and it is working fine.But in my actual database the field names are different than header names and i cannot change database field names and also i cannot include database field names to datatable header .Please help how i can update to database.

I am using JDBC for database operations.My code is exactly similar as below.

My JSF page

```
<h:form id="form">

  <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

  <p:dataTable id="multiCars" var="car"
     value="#{tableBean.mediumCarsModel}" paginator="true" rows="10"
     selection="#{tableBean.selectedCars}" editable="true" editMode="cell">

     <f:facet name="header"> 
        Checkbox Based Selection 
    </f:facet>
     <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onCellEdit}"
        update=":form:messages" />

     <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%" />


     <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:25%">
        <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output">
              <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
           </f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input">
              <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{car.model}"
                 style="width:96%" />
           </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
     </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="Year" style="width:25%">
        <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output">
              <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
           </f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input">
              <p:inputText value="#{car.year}" style="width:96%" label="Year" />
           </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
     </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="Manufacturer" style="width:25%">
        <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output">
              <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />
           </f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input">
              <p:inputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" style="width:96%"
                 label="Year" />
           </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
     </p:column>


     <p:column headerText="Color" style="width:25%">
        <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output">
              <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
           </f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input">
              <p:inputText value="#{car.color}" style="width:96%" label="Year" />
           </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
     </p:column>

     <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton id="multiViewButton" value="View"
           icon="ui-icon-search" actionListener="#{tableBean.getSelection}" />
     </f:facet>
  </p:dataTable>
```

My Managed bean onCellEdit method

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) { 
  System.out.println("inside cell edit");

  UIColumn col= event.getColumn();
  DataTable o=(DataTable) event.getSource();
  Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();  //here i get old value
  Object newValue = event.getNewValue(); //new value
  Car info=(Car)o.getRowData();
  String newModel=info.getModel();//primary key

  System.out.println("row index in event method "+event.getRowIndex());
  System.out.println("old value"+oldValue);
  System.out.println("new value"+newValue);
  System.out.println("column2 :"+col.getHeaderText());//header text value


  try{


     updateStmt=connection.createStatement();


     String query = "update test set " + col.getHeaderText() +"= '"+ newValue +"' where Model = '"+newModel+"'";

     int i=updateStmt.executeUpdate(query);
     if(i!=0)
        System.out.println("updated!!!");
     else
        System.out.println("not updated!!!");

  }
  catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }


  if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) { 
     FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue); 
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg); 
  }
```

}